# Sitecore converting Lucene to Solr

Tags: sitecore, solrnet, sitecore8

Currently, I have lucene search engine in my sitecore 8 instance. It is working perfectly but something change in our production servers. The production servers now are 2 content delivery server with load balancing and a content management server.

I read that it is difficult to use lucene in this kind of architecture. They are suggesting to use Solr instead of lucene.

I am able to setup solr with the help of this [post](https://sitecore-community.github.io/docs/search/solr/Configuring-Solr-for-use-with-Sitecore-8/). It is working perfectly and I able to create indexes for sitecore_web_index, sitecore_master_index, sitecore_core_index and sitecore_analytics_index.

What I am having trouble is converting my custom search index configuration to SOLR configuration (schema.xml).

My search index configuration contains computed fields and an include template (`<include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">`) that index only those specific fields.

Question:

1. How to create sitecore computed fields in SOLR (schema.xml)?
2. How to index only a particular template?

> ```
> <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
>        <page>{GUID}</page>
> </include>
> ```

I already checked the samples in [solrTutorial.com](http://www.solrtutorial.com/schema-xml.html) but can't find what I am looking for (Noob!).

Looking forward to learn from you guys.

UPDATE:

Implementing the suggestion of nsgocev I received the error below:

[image]

Update 2:

Looks like setting the Initialize on Add to true cause the problem:

```
<initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd>
```

Please let me know what I am missing.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically using computed fields is the same like using it with your Lucene indexes. The idea is to add your fields in your `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.*` configurations instead in your `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Lucene.*` configurations. In the Solr configs (Most likely the `Sitecore.ContentSearch.Solr.DefaultIndexConfiguration.config`) there should be `<fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">` section where you just need to add your computed field like this:

```xml
 <fields hint="raw:AddComputedIndexField">
     ...
     <field fieldName="mycomputedfield"             returnType="string">YourNamespace.MyComputedField, YourAssembly</field>
 </fields>
```

Same goes for indexing on a particular template. There is a list in the same configuration file (commented out by default)

```xml
<!-- <include hint="list:IncludeTemplate">
    <BucketFolderTemplateId>{ADB6CA4F-03EF-4F47-B9AC-9CE2BA53FF97}</BucketFolderTemplateId>
</include>-->
```

Comment: Oh, looks like I missed that one. I am looking at the schema.xml. HAHAHA! I will try your suggestion.

Comment: Hi nsgov, please see the updates in my question. I encountered an error.

Comment: @Pinoy2015 are you sure you configured your indexes correctly ? Seems like a miss configuration to me.

Comment: You are correct looks like settings this <initializeOnAdd>true</initializeOnAdd> to true causes the issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Thanks, it is working now even though the initiazeOnAdd is set to false.